# compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3 how to fix error. i get every time error with any firebase ui dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, javac, firebaseui

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details how to fix this error please ans me

**my `build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mayur.mahadev"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' ?>
```

how to fix this error pls help me

Comment: Add the details of your gradle error.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the compiler error output ;;; this error i get in message view..

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You are using:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

As described [in the documentation:](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries)

> Each version of FirebaseUI has dependency on a fixed version of these libraries, defined as the variable firebase_version in `common/constants.gradle`. If you are using any dependencies in your app of the form `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-*:x.y.z'` or `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:x.y.z'` **you need to make sure that you use the same version that your chosen version of FirebaseUI requires.**

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
1.2.0               10.2.0
1.1.1               10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.1               10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.0               9.8.0
0.6.2               9.8.0
0.6.1               9.6.1
0.6.0               9.6.0
0.5.3               9.4.0
0.4.4               9.4.0
0.4.3               9.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your build.gradle(project) file as follows:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

Hope you will find a solution.